# How to move category to another parent category magento 2.1.8?

Tags: admin, category-tree, magento-2.1.8

I want to move a category from parent category to another parent category.

category Drag and drop from admin is too slow. So how can I do this using code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help for you,

First create one test file in root directory with below content and run **www.example.com/test.php**

```
$mobile_id = 246;
$mobile_cover_id = 116;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($mobile_cover_id);
$category->move($mobile_id, null);
```

Comment: I am asking about magento 2. BTW Thanks, I have done.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categoryId = 183;
$parentId = 540;
$rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
$cat_info = $rootCat->load($categoryId);
$cat_info->move($parentId, null);
```